# Which method to use for injecting EJB?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.1

I have read many posts both online and SO, but I am still not clear on to which annotation to use for injecting an EJB.

Can anyone please guide when to use which annotation for injecting an EJB (and possibly pros and cons):

> 1) @EJB
>   2) @Resource
>   3) @Inject

This might be a basic question, I did look for answers, but I am not still clear on this.

Comment: @Resource is used by Spring as well.  I think it would still apply if you decided to use POJOs instead of EJBs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never seen anywhere that you could use `@Resource` for injecting an EJB. It *might* work in some servers but it is unlikely to be portable.

The question of `@EJB` vs `@Inject` is more complicated.

CDI and `@Inject` were added to the Java EE 6 Specification. There it was possible to @Inject EJBs into a CDI bean, but not in too many other (if any) places.

The Java EE 7 Specification unified this substantially to the point where you can use `@Inject` or `@EJB` interchangeably in most (if not all) places. In essence all of the "sub" specifications such as the EJB spec itself, the servlet spec, JAX-WS, JAX-RS, etc had to be updated to support the use of `@Inject` as well as `@EJB`. However if you need to specify any of the attributes available on the @EJB annotation then these are not available on @Inject.

Therefore, feel free to use `@Inject` anywhere if you're running in a Java EE 7 compliant environment and you don't have a need for any of the @EJB attributes, otherwise use `@EJB`.